# Attach to previously started async process

Tags: c#, async-await

So i have an app that works using a token for a user. User can be signed in only on 1 device ( after login previous tokens get expired ). So i came up with an idea to cache some data. So i created a CacheManager that is a singleton.

CacheManager has a Dictionary with previously fetched data in it.

So here is an example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Tries to get Global settings data from the cache. If it is not present - asks ServiceManager to fetch it.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Global setting object</returns>
public async Task<GlobalSettingsModel> GetGlobalSettingAsync()
{
    GlobalSettingsModel result;

    if (!this.cache.ContainsKey("GlobalSettings"))
    {
        result = await ServiceManager.Instance.RequestGlobalSettingAsync();
        if (result != null)
        {
            this.cache.Add("GlobalSettings", result);
        }

        // TODO: Figure out what to do in case of null
    }

    return (GlobalSettingsModel)this.cache["GlobalSettings"];
}
```

So the question is, how can i modify this method, to handle such case:

For example, method that i call from the server, works longer than user navigated to the page where the data is needed i want to show a loading indicator and hide it when the data has actually been received.

Why do i need it, we have 2 pages - ExtendedSplashScreen and UpdatesPage user can quickly skip them ( 1s ) or stay and read interesting info ( lets say 1m ).
In this time, i have started to fetch the GetGlobalSetting in order to have the process ended or download atleast something ( to minify wait for the user ) when he gets to LoginPage.

On my ExtendedSplashScreen i launched:

```
CacheManager.Instance.GetGlobalSettingAsync();
```

For test purposes, i have modified the ServiceManager method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Fetches the object of Global Settings from the server
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Global setting object</returns>
public async Task<GlobalSettingsModel> RequestGlobalSettingAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(60000);

    // Request and response JSONs are here, because we will need them to be logged if any unexpected exceptions will occur

    // Response JSON
    string responseData = string.Empty;

    // Request JSON
    string requestData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new GlobalSettingsRequestModel());

    // Posting list of keys that we want to get from GlobalSettings table
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("ServerMethod", new StringContent(requestData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

    // TODO: HANDLE ALL THE SERVER POSSIBLE ERRORS

    Stream receiveStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

    // Read the response data
    responseData = readStream.ReadToEnd();

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GlobalSettingsResponseModel>(responseData).GlobalSettings;
}
```

So, when user gets to the LoginPage i do the:

```
// The await is here because there is no way without this data further
GlobalSettingsModel settings = await CacheManager.Instance.GetGlobalSettingAsync();
```

**And here, i would like to get the data from the cache if it was already downloaded or that CacheManager would return me the data as soon as it will be finished downloading.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to cache the `Task<GlobalSettingsModel>` instead of the `GlobalSettingsModel` itself. When you obtain it from the cache, you could check if it has completed and then either await or use its result accordingly.